# How to go destroy method in CategoryController in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I want to delete data using modal, I already get the id of the data I want to delete, but when I click the delete button in modal nothing happen.. Please tell me if something wrong. Thank you very much.

I'm having an issue getting data to transfer into my delete confirmation modal. I've verified my delete route works in removing data from the data base but the issue I'm facing is that I can't pass the `categoty->id` into the modal to access for deletion.

blade and ajax

```
 @extends('Admin.master')

@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-10 p-5 pt-2">
        <h3><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt ml-2"></i>دسته بندی ها</h3><hr>
        <a href="{{ route('categories.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
            افزودن دسته بندی جدید
        </a>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>نام دسته</th>
                    <th>تاریخ ایجاد شده</th>
                    <th>اکشن ها</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $category->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $category->created_at }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                <a href="{{ route('categories.edit', $category->id) }}"  class="btn btn-primary">ویرایش</a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-action="{{ route('categories.destroy', $category->id) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteCategory">حذف</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteCategory" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteCategory" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <form action="{{ route('categories.destroy', $category->id) }}">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">این عمل برگشت پذیر نیست..</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        آیا از حذف {{ $category->name }} اطمینان دارید؟
                        <input type="hidden" id="category" name="category">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn bg-white" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-action="{{ route('categories.destroy', $category->id) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteCategory">حذف</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('script')
    <script>
        $('#deleteCategory').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var action = button.data('action');
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('form').attr('action', action);
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

CategoryController.php

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    dd($category);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
```

I want go to `destroy` method in `CategoryController.php`.

It didn't even show `dd`.

Comment: The request type should be DELETE `type: 'DELETE',` in your ajax function. If you run `php artisan route:list` in your console you can see all routes and the ype of request you need to make to access that specific function in your back-end

Comment: @JairoNavaMagaña I updated my posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should change the way your setup is. In my opinion the way you want to setup the form would work if the form is in another page, so when the delete category button is clicked the browser redirects to another page instead of the modal.
To make it work the way I think you want it you could use some HTML data attributes.
First the form in the modal should be something like

```
<form id="form-delete-category">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">این عمل برگشت پذیر نیست..</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <!-- a span is used as a container to show the category name -->
      آیا از حذف <span id="category-name"></span> اطمینان دارید؟
      <input type="hidden" id="category" name="category">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn bg-white" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
      <!-- this is button type so no submit event is triggered -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="handle_delete">حذف</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now the button to open the modal can be changed to:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-category="{{$category}}" id="btn-delete-category">حذف</button>
```

I set the whole category object, but you can use only what you need. In this case your JS changes a little.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-category-id="{{$category->id}}" data-category-name="{{$category->name}}" id="btn-delete-category">حذف</button>
```

In your java-script you add a function to handle the click event, like so:

```
$("#btn-delete-category").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // get the category object using the data() function
  let  category = $(this).data('category');
  
  /**
   * If only the name and id where set just get them separatly
   * 
   * let  id = $(this).data('category-id');
   * let  name = $(this).data('category-name');
  */

  // Set the variables in your dom
  $('#category-name').html(category.name);
  $('#category').html(category.id);

  // Generate the URL to delete this category
  $('#form-delete-category').attr('action', route_to_delete_category + category.id);

  // Show the modal
  $('#deleteCategory').modal('show');

});

$("#handle_delete").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Show loading state

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'DELETE'
  })
  .done(function(response) {
    // Hide loading state
    // Show success message
    $('#deleteCategory').modal('hide');
  })

});
```